# listView doesn't show content

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I'm working with `ListView` in C#.NET.

I'm using code similar to this:

```
string[] row1 = { "s1", "s2", "s3" };
listView1.Items.Add("Column1Text").SubItems.AddRange(row1);
```

However I can't see the content, only the name of the column. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're adding subitems.  I don't know what columns you're showing, but the first column will be the item text itself, with further columns being the subitems.

So, if I want to show A B C, I need to add an item of A with two subitems of B and C.  That will show all three.  If you want to see all three in your example, do an Items.Add on each one.  They'll all fill the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("Column1Text"); 
 item.SubItems.AddRange(row1); 
 listView1.Items.Add(item);
 listView1.View = View.Details;
```

Comment: well I think I found the problem...I didnt create columnHeaders...before...
if I want to add another array (row2) for another row..? I tried:
 ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("Co1");
            item.SubItems.AddRange(row1);
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
            ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("Co2");
            item.SubItems.AddRange(row2);
            listView1.Items.Add(item1);
            listView1.View = View.Details;
but Im not getting the data in the in Item1 but in Item..? any idea what Im doing wrong?
Ty!! ^_^)